# Add new network interface to the kvm (Slackware is installed)

Tags: kvm, slackware, networkcard

Installed slackware11 on KVM, which is controlled by virt-manager. I need one more network interface, so I added another one using the same model as was installed by default, and restarted the machine. But the `ifconfig` command just shows the `lo` and `eth0`.

Should I do any job on Linux after adding interfaces to KVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `ifconfig` itself provides only a list of interfaces which are up, i.e. interfaces which are somehow already configured.

To see all the interfaces use `ifconfig -a` or `ip address show`